# How to download a new apk file from an sql server and update the app with the new apk version

Tags: android, sql-server, apk

I have a windows sql server where i have uploaded a new version of my application apk file. Now i would like to download the apk in code and save it on my device, and then refresh the application so it would run the new version. If that is not possible i would need a solution where i have 2 applications where app A will do the version checking and optional updates, and then auto start app B where will be the actuall app i want users to use.

I have seen similar solutions where developers are downloading the file from a http server, but i dont have that option and have to use the database to get the file. Is there a way to use InputStream to locate a file that is not a web URL but a byte[] recieved from tge database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

```
private void downloadNewVersion(ArrayList<CustomFileObjectWithIDAndFilePath> fileList) {

    CallableStatement statement = null;

    try {
        statement = con.prepareCall("{call some_stored_procedure (?)}");
        statement.setInt(1, fileList.get(0).ID);
        statement.execute();
        ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();


            while (rs.next()){

                byte[] fileContent= rs.getBytes("File");

                FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileList.get(0).name));
                fs.write(fileContent, 0, fileContent.length);

                fs.flush();
                fs.close();
            }


    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Than i just run a method to start an intent in which i install that downloaded file.

Answer (score 0):

change in manifest file

```
android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
```

update versionCode to "2"